# Keyboard stopped working, mouse still works

Tags: usb, keyboard

My wired keyboard randomly stopped working on my Raspberry Pi 3 after working fine for two weeks. My wired mouse still works fine.

I've tried swapping both into all 4 ports and the mouse works in all of them and the keyboard in none of them. The keyboard still works fine when I plug it into my mac. All other functionality on my Pi seems to work fine except the keyboard.

Comment: The next thing to check is another keyboard. It could be an USB power problem. Plug in a powered hub, and connect the keyboard to the hub.

Comment: Ok borrowed a friends keyboard to test and their keyboard works on my Pi but I will need to return the keyboard soon. I'm still hoping to troubleshoot the issue with the initial keyboard (it should work since it works on my mac)

Comment: It could still be a power problem. Also, a mac keyboard has an internal hub if I remember correctly. Is some power-hungry device plugged in there? A bluetooth or wifi adapter maybe?

Comment: No bluetooth or wifi adapter. I do have a wired mouse, a monitor plugged in, ethernet plugged in, and a pi camera connected. I was using an "Insignia" wired keyboard and switched to an "HP" wired keyboard which now works.

It seems weird that it would be a power issue since my set up has been working fine for a couple weeks now and I didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyboard was drawing too much power. I replaced it with another keyboard and now it all works fine.